# SQLite - Determine average sales made for each day of week

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to produce a query in SQLite where I can determine the average sales made each weekday in the year.

As an example, I'd say like to say

"The average sales for Monday are $400.50 in 2017"

I have a sales table - each row represents a sale you made. You can have multiple sales for the same day. Columns that would be of interest here:

```
Id, SalesTotal, DayCreated, MonthCreated, YearCreated, CreationDate, PeriodOfTheDay
```

Day/Month/Year are integers that represent the day/month/year of the week. DateCreated is a unix timestamp that represents the date/time it was created too (and is obviously equal to day/month/year).

PeriodOfTheDay is 0, or 1 (day, or night). You can have multiple records for a given day (typically you can have at most 2 but some people like to add all of their sales in individually, so you could have 5 or more for a day).

**Where I am stuck**

Because you can have two records on the same day (i.e. a day sales, and a night sales, or multiple of each) I can't just group by day of the week (i.e. group all records by Saturday).

This is because the number of sales you made does not equal the number of days you worked (i.e. I could have worked 10 saturdays, but had 30 sales, so grouping by 'saturday' would produce 30 sales since 30 records exist for saturday (some just happen to share the same day)

Furthermore, if I group by daycreated,monthcreated,yearcreated it works in the sense it produces x rows (where x is the number of days you worked) however that now means I need to return this resultset to the back end and do a row count. I'd rather do this in the query so I can take the sales and divide it by the number of days you worked.

Would anyone be able to assist?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I think I got it - I would love someone to tell me if I'm right:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(( julianday((datetime(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'))) ) / 7 AS INT)) 
FROM Sales
WHERE strftime('%w', datetime(CreationDate / 1000, 'unixepoch'), 'localtime') =  '6' 
  AND YearCreated = 2017
```

This would produce the number for saturday, and then I'd just put this in as an inner query, dividing the sale total by this number of days.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy,

You can group your query by getting the day of week and week number of day created or creation date.

In MSSQL

```
DATEPART(WEEK,'2017-08-14') // Will give you week 33
DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2017-08-14') // Will give you day 2
```

In MYSQL

```
WEEK('2017-08-14') // Will give you week 33
DAYOFWEEK('2017-08-14') // Will give you day 2
```

See this figures..

```
Day of Week
1-Sunday, 2- Monday, 3-Tuesday, 4-Wednesday, 5-Thursday, 6-Saturday

Week Number
1 - 53 Weeks in a year
```

This will be the key so that you will have a separate Saturday's in every month.

Hope this can help in building your query.

Comment: Thanks @OzLa - I made a mistake I put MySQL I meant SqlLIte but regardless, I did what you suggested, grouping it by both. It produced rows (so not just one value), but the total count of those rows is the value I want. The thing is, this means now I'd have to pass the resultset back to PHP to count the records, but I'd really like to just get the total count in SQL. Any ideas how to do that now? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a dummy data and expected output to build the query? We could test your query on it, if its feasable